# nodejs + redis - prevent instance to process the same message sent by itself

Tags: node.js, redis

I'm running identical socket.io instances on separate servers for my project.

My goal is, prevent publisher instance to process its own message.

```
var publisherId = 'EdswFd';

subscriber.on('message', function (channel, message) {
    if(channel == 'new process'){
        if(message == publisherId) {
            //prevent processing message
            return console.log('same instance');
        }
        else
        {
            //process message
        }
    }
});

publisher.publish('new process', publisherId);
```

By this, I'm trying to achieve below:

```
             |     |
             |     | -do-not-process-> socket1
socket1 ---> |redis|
             |     | -process-message-> socket2
             |     |
```

The problem is, publisher instance tries to process own message 3 times instantly and other instance never gets the message.

Is there a way to prevent after first attempt?

I tried to unsubscribe publisher and resubscribe after a while but, I don't think that is a good practice and it didn't work either...